# Colocar efeito de espaçamento em inicio de parágrafo

Tags: html, css

**Cenário**: Tenho uma página de Termos de serviço e responsabilidades. Por ser muito verboso, há cerca de 15 parágrafos. Para gerar o espaçamento inicial de cada parágrafo estou usando um conjuto de: **5** `&nbsp;` porém quero remover estes `&nbsp;`.

**Pergunta**: como farei para dar este efeito de inicio de parágrafo sem usar este `&nbsp;`?

**HTML reduzido da página**:

```
<p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS
</p>
<p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS
</p>
<p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS
</p>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode utilizar a propriedade [`text-indent`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp):

```css
p {
    text-indent: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since. 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, 'just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'</p>

<p>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since. 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, 'just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'</p>
```

Comment: Não conhecia esta propriedade text-indent

Comment: É pouco utilizada porque na _web_ não se tem o costume de espaçar parágrafos, como é comumente feitos em documentos físicos. Mas existe desde a versão 1 do CSS.

Comment: A título de curiosidade: A propriedade `text-indent` era muito utilizada para esconder textos mas ainda assim permitir que eles existissem no HTML, o que era usado para melhores posições em buscadores (`text-indent:-9999px`), até que esta prática foi desencorajada pela Google e desde então não vem mais sendo tão utilizada.

Answer (score 4):

Como fiz para resolver esta questão: utilizei o pseudo elemento `:first-letter` ficando da seguinte forma:

**CSS**:

```
p:first-letter {
    margin-left: 3em;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<p>
TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS
</p>
<p>
TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS
</p>
<p>
TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS TOS
</p>
```